# Passing default value to form view using context (Odoo 13)

Tags: python, odoo

I have 3 models ; I want to use context to get default values when passing from view to other.
How can I do that ? Any help please ?

When creating patient , I will choose or create an appointment. I would to get value "patient_id"  of the model 'hospital.rdv' by default .

Also I have a button action to create an operation from 'hospital.patient' model, so , fields 'date' , 'patient_name ' must be by default.

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
     _name = 'hospital.patient'
    patient_id = fields.Many2one(hospital.rdv)


class Rendez-vous(models.Model):
     _name = 'hospital.rdv'
    hospital_rdv_id = fields.Many2one(hospital.patient)
    Date = fields.Date(string="Date")
    patient_name = fields.Char(string="Name")


class Operation(models.Model):
    _name = 'hospital.operation'
    patient_id = fields.Many2one(hospital.rdv)
    Date = fields.Date(string="Date")
    patient_name = fields.Char(string="Name")
```

Thanks

Comment: You could set the default on the models. It would be nice if you provide infos about your environment/ project and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Some scenarios:-

If You have wizard and you would like pass value to wizard from your current form.

```
<record id="your_action_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Action name</field>
    <field name="res_model">model of wizard</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="context">{'default_your_field_name': value_od_your_field}</field>
</record>
```

Now If you have **many2one** field or **one2many** field in your model and you want to pass context as user select create and edit button from fields.

Use this:-

```
<field name="your_model_field" context="{'default_relation_model_field_name': value_of_that_field}"/>
```

If you still not understand feel free to ask.

Comment: I'm using many2one fields not wizard ,...                                                                         <field name="hospital.rdv"  context="{'default_values': patient_id}" />  ; must I use related field ? I don't uderstand what "default_relation_model_field_name" is ?

Comment: In which field you want to pass the value , this field name is after default_fieldname. And in value just pass the value of that field.

Comment: I want to pass the value of 'patient_id' field in model  'hospital.patient' to ''hospital_rdv_id" field in 'hospital.rdv' (when creating or selecting a record)  and to get default values : Date, patient_name corresponding to 'hospital.rdv' in the model 'hospital.operation'

Comment: Those two are different models. You can not pass value of patient_id to hospital_rdv_id. Now in your scenario put the related fields like  patient_name, date field in your hospital.patient model , after that you can pass the value from patient model to rdv model.